# Solving this Differential Equation (from string equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following differential equation:
$$ au(x) - b\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u(x) + cu^2(x) - x = 0 $$
The reference says, it might be related to the Painlevé differential equation III but I don't see it and I don't know the solution to it.

If any know how to solve it (analytically or numerically), please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What reference?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10959

Comment: I don't see Painlevé mentioned there. Anyhow: setting $u=\alpha q+\beta$, $x=\gamma t+\delta$, you may reduce your differential equation to $q_{tt}=6q^2+t$ by appropriate choice of constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$. This is the standard form of the first Painlevé equation. It has no single closed-form solution known so far (in fact there are Galois-type theorems saying such solutions cannot exist). Numerically, however, it can be solved in the same way as any other ODE (e.g. with NDSolve in Mathematica).